# get probabilities for knn model in R

Tags: machine-learning, r

I've gotten the classes for my model, but I want to get probabilities but am not sure how to set the 'Task' parameter. I get this error: Error in train(lrn, task = cr.fit) :
Assertion on 'task' failed: Must inherit from class 'Task', but has classes 'train','train.formula'.

Can someone please help me figure out how I would set the 'Task' parameter?

```
trCtrl <- trainControl(method = 'cv', number = 5, classProbs = TRUE, search="grid", summaryFunction=twoClassSummary)

cr.fit <- caret::train (Outcome~., data=balanced.train, method = "knn",
               trControl = trCtrl, metric = "ROC")

pred = predict(cr.fit, newdata=select(test_covid_predictor,-Outcome))

# adjust threshold and predict probabilities 

lrn = makeLearner("classif.kknn", predict.type = "prob")
mod = train(lrn, task = cr.fit)

threshold = c(FATAL = 0.4)
predict= setThreshold(pred, threshold = threshold)
```

Thank you!!

Comment: When I try this: `pred = predict(cr.fit, newdata=select(test_covid_predictor,-Outcome),type="prob") ` , I get the probabilities but when I generate the confusion matrix with my test set using `confusionMatrix(data=pred,reference=test_covid_predictor$Outcome) `,                             
 I get the following error: Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.